# Which is faster ASP.NET or PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

I need to do some server side programming to read through a database. The database will have about a thousand entries per user. Reading through the database will take a little while, so I need to know which language is faster, ASP.NET or PHP. Thank you.

Comment: Try it, use it and test it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET and PHP are very close in terms of speed. PHP tends to be a little faster, see here: http://www.comentum.com/php-vs-asp.net-comparison.html. As you will see, most of the larger companies that have to read though very large databases tend to use PHP. But since ASP.NET and PHP are so close in rearms of speed, you should take into account which one is more common. In this case, PHP is far more common.

Note: PHP is written in C, so it may be faster to use C rather than PHP.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you Progo, you have answered my question. The URL was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked here many times and it's impossible to answer such question. Do a research on both the languages PHP and ASP.NET and than ask your self which one is best for this task. Both the languages are very fast but it depends on you what you want to take